# How does the C# TextMetrics properties work?

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how the C# TextMetrics properties work. The example below, that I found somewhere and modified a bit, does something, but the result seems to be 7 no matter what font I set in the textbox.

```
TextMetrics metrics;
VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit.Normal);
using (IDeviceContext context = textBox1.CreateGraphics() as IDeviceContext)
{
    metrics = renderer.GetTextMetrics(context);
}
int averageWidth = metrics.AverageCharWidth;
textBox1.Text = averageWidth.ToString(); // 7
```

MSDN doesn't provide any examples, and I haven't found anything comprehensible on any other web site. Could someone explain how this works?

PS: I want to use all the TextMetrics properties. Not just AverageCharWidth.

Update: I'm writing a font viewer, using private font collection. I want to get as much information about each font as I can. Then I can decide what's useful to include in the font viewer and what's not.

My font viewer reminds about Bitstream Font Navigator (http://noscope.com/2004/font-management-solution/), but I want to include more information about the fonts.

Update: I can use FontFamily methods to get some of that information, as Olivier Jacot-Descombes points out in his answer, but not all. I think I need to use TextMetrics to get information about, for example, PitchAndFamily, MaxCharWidth and AverageCharWidth. Or is there some other simple way to get this information?

Comment: The font of a TextBox is not fixed by the visual style, it is set by the Font property.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to change the font, use the `TextBox.Font` property, as Hans pointed out. If you're trying to do something else, tell us what it is.

Comment: The question is not about the Textbox; it's about TextMetrics.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve font metrics like this

```
var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11f);
var style = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular;
var ff = font.FontFamily;
int ascent = ff.GetCellAscent(style);
int descent = ff.GetCellDescent(style);
int height = ff.GetEmHeight(style);
int lineSpacing = ff.GetLineSpacing(style);
float pointSize = font.SizeInPoints;
```

For more information see [How to: Obtain Font Metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Useful information if you don't know how to use the FontFamily class. However, the question is about TextMetrics - NOT about the FontFamily class.

Comment: It's just another way of returning metrics.

Comment: How do you get PitchAndFamily, MaxCharWidth and AverageCharWidth with the FontFamily class?

Comment: You can't, but `FontFamily` yields different, possibly useful metrics.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I asked a very specific question about TextMetrics. But I guess not very many people know how to use TextMetrics. Several google searches gave VERY few examples.